# Why is the ratio of any two sides of an equilateral triangle on a complex plane equal to a complex cubic root of unity?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, triangles

> Why is the ratio of any two sides of an equilateral triangle on a complex plane equal to a complex root of unity?

This question is derived from an excerpt from the following [note](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://online.sfsu.edu/ycheung/730/hw3soln.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjm5tGhm9rdAhVFJ30KHRDnAR8QFjABegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw32g-7Uy1rkCJskyswmoV21), which states that:

"If $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are vertices of an equilateral triangle, then triple of complex numbers $a_1 − a_2, a_2 −a_3$ and $a_3 −a_1$ have the same length and the ratio of any consecutive pair is the same (complex) cube root of unity."

I am not sure why the case is true. I know how to represent a ratio of two complex numbers on a complex plane but I am lost on how to prove my question.

Intuitive AND rigorous answer would be greatly appreciated, though either is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are the vertices of the triangle then $a_1-a_2, a_2 -a_3, a_3-a_1$ are `vectors' representing the edges of the triangle.

You can turn one edge of an equilateral triangle into the next edge by rotating it by angle $2\pi/3$. This corresponds to multiplication by $e^{2\pi i 3}$, aka the complex cube root of unity.

In other words, $a_1-a_2 = e^{2\pi i /3} (a_2-a_3)$ and so on.